# Linq - Get items from the list based on "weight" and "order"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I am trying to create a class which compute the *completeness* of a profile of a user and I am trying to get the next steps (Evaluators) in order for the user to achieve the next *completeness* level.

```
public class Evaluator
{
    public Evaluator(string name, int value, Func<CompletionStatus, bool> rule)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Action = rule;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public Func<Completion, bool> Rule { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get;set; }

    public int Run(CompletionStatus status)
    {
         IsCompleted = Rule(status);
         return IsCompleted ? Value : 0;        
    }
}

class CompletionManager
{
     public List<Evaluator> Evaluators { get;set; }

     public CompletionManager() {

        Evaluators = new List<Evaluator>() {
        new Evaluator("Email", 10, status => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(status.Email)),
        new Evaluator("DOB", 10, status => status.DateOfBirth.HasValue),
        new Evaluator("Mobile", 20, status => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(status.Mobile)),
        new Evaluator("Address", 20, status => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( status.Address)),
        new Evaluator("Profession", 40, status => status.HasProfession),

    };
}
```

Usage

```
  Main() {

   var status = new CompletionStatus
            {
                Email = "dummy@gmail.com",
                DateOfBirth = null,
                Mobile = "",
                Address = "",
                HasProfession = false,
            };

    CompletionManager cm = new CompletionManager();

     var profileCompletion = (byte) cm.Evaluators
            .Select(evaluator => evaluator.Run(status))
            .Sum();

     profileCompletion.Dump(); // result= 10% complete

     var nextEvaluators = cm.EvaluatorsToTheNextLevel(profileCompletion); // get the next 40%

 }
```

Problem: In this example - how do I get the list of `Evaluator` that correspond to the next 40% that the user have to complete so that the profile completion is `>= 50%`;

In the example above, I want to get the `Evaluator("DOB")`, `Evaluator("Mobile")` and `Evaluator("Address")`

```
class CompletionManager {
....
 public List<Evaluator> EvaluatorsToTheNextLevel(int completionStatus) {

    // assuming completionStatus = 10%, then we have to get the next 40% worth of evaluators
       var percentBeforeNxtLevel = 50 - completionStatus;
       return Evaluators.Where(e => e.IsCompleted == false && ???);
   }
}
```

Note: order of Evaluators is also considered so if we are getting the next 40%, we dont want the `Evaluator("Profession")` as it is in the bottom of the stack

And Also: THIS should be flexible; if I do

```
var status = new CompletionStatus
            {
                Email = "",
                DateOfBirth = null,
                Mobile = "091920",
                Address = "",
                HasProfession = false,
            };
```

then we should get `Evaluator("Email"), Evaluator("DOB"), Evaluator("Address")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that :

```
public List<Evaluator> EvaluatorsToTheNextLevel(int completionStatus) {

    // assuming completionStatus = 10%, then we have to get the next 40% worth of evaluators
       var percentBeforeNxtLevel = 50 - completionStatus;
       var tmp = 0;
       return Evaluators
          .Where(e => e.IsCompleted == false)
          .TakeWhile(x => {
              tmp +=x.Value;
              return tmp <= percentBeforeNxtLevel;
            })
           .ToList();
   }
```

Of course, this could be also easily achieved with a simple `while` loop...

Answer (score 0):

The line below will not work

```css
.Select(evaluator => evaluator.Run(status))
​
```

You are enumerating through the evaluators one at a time in the order that they go into the List<>.  Your function needs all the evaluators to you need to pass the entire list 'Evaluators'.